# Can we say that inside alternator magnetic force create now force (voltage)

Tags: voltage

Can we say that inside an alternator, magnetic force creates a new force (voltage), and those two forces together transform mechanical to electrical energy?

Comment: You can say that, but I don't see how it advances understanding in any meaningful way. Strictly speaking, voltage is not a force; it is a measure of potential energy.

Comment: It can be known as "electromotive force, measured in volts.

Comment: It is reasonable to say, if you are speaking to a non-technical audience.

Comment: @DaveTweed  Voltage is not "a measure of potential energy" (a very widespread misconception.)  P.E. is proportional to the charge, in the same way that PE is proportional to the mass of a boulder.  Voltage is like gravity: a way to measure a field.  The g-field is still there, hanging in the empty space above the ground, even when the boulder is missing and the PE is zero.  Voltage is still there, hanging in space, even when no charge is being moved and PE=0.  Finally: measuring voltage tells us nothing about the stored PE since 2X the charge will double the PE, if voltage is constant.

Comment: @wbeaty: Congratulations on out-pedanting me! You are, of course, correct. I was being overly terse. You should consider writing up your thoughts as an actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

In an alternator, the mechanical input spins the rotor, which has a magnetic field. This moving field induces a voltage in the stator windings. If there's no load connected to the stator, no current flows, and the mechanical energy required is only enough to overcome mechanical friction in the bearings and air resistance.

If a load is connected, allowing a current to flow in the stator windings, this current creates a new magnetic field that opposes the motion of the rotor's field. This is "felt" as additional mechanical resistance by the prime mover, and it must supply additional energy to keep the alternator running at the same speed.

Does this clarify things at all for you? [Faraday's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction) covers the relationship between magnetic fields, motion and voltage, while [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) deals with the relationship between voltage, current and power in the load.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that a coil of wire moving in a certain way through a magnetic field will generate a terminal voltage like this: -

[image]

Image taken from [**here**](http://slideplayer.com/1595833/5/images/41/Generator+A+coil+of+wire+turns+in+a+magnetic+field..jpg)

For a perfectly efficient scenario and no load connected to the output (i.e. no light bulb) there are no physical forces involved other than the initial force of spinning the coil up to a certain constant speed.

Electrical energy occurs when a load is connected and that energy is turned into heat and light by the light bulb or load). To sustain that energy delivery, a sustained mechanical energy (or work) is needed and, for this "perfect" system, the power consumed by the light bulb equals the mechanical power put into the shaft.

So, magnetism and mechancial power get converted to electrical power.

Comment: Point taken, but strictly speaking this is a dynamo not an alternator. The advantage of an alternator is that the power output is taken from stator windings and does not have to go through slip rings/commutator.

Comment: @RoyC a dynamo produces DC and uses a commutator from what I remember

Comment: Agreed but the principal is the same the whole point is that the power output does not need to be transmitted off a rotating shaft.

Comment: @RoyC in the context of this question that is extremely fine detail and I would say irrelevant.

Comment: I did say point taken :).

Comment: @RoyC - hehe I did a check on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternator) and it says: "Occasionally, a linear alternator or a rotating armature with a stationary magnetic field is used" - then they say that is called a magneto but, according to the article it is grouped as a type of alternator.

Comment: don't look too closely at those "slip rings"